# How do I make scala program loop and read every letter in string

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make the program go through a predetermined string and read each character 1 by 1 in a manner similar to what I have posted. The IDE tells me that I cannot do "cs >= 1" because ">=" is not part of "(Char => Boolean) => Int".

```
def move(s: String) {
  var chemov = s.take(1)
  var cs = s.count(_)
  while (cs >= 1){
    ad()
    s.drop(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: note that ```s``` does not modify by ```s.drop(1)```. That function returns the string without the first character. Also ```cs```, never updates, so even if ```cs``` was an integer, the loop would never terminate.

Comment: What is your intention with the variable ```chemov```? It contains the first character of ```s```, but since it is never used, and ```s.take(1)``` does not modify ```s```, the operation has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

`s.count()` does not give you the length of the s, but it gives you the number of occurences that the predicate matches. By just supplying an underscore, `cs` is not an integer, but a function. That is why you get your error. You can get the size with `s.length`

If you want to use `count`, then you have to supply a function:

```
var cs = s.count(_ => true)
```

Alternatively, you can just iterate over the string:

```
s.foreach( c => {
    ad()
})
```